# Can't nest a class and change css for it?

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to get this class to function with css, I have tried it with id and class when I type hello into the html `offset-top-left` it shows but the css doesn't show its attributes?

html

```html
<div class="target">
  <div id="interface-reg">
    <div class="top left"><div class="offset-top-left"></div></div>
    <div class="top right"></div>
    <div class="bottom left"></div>
    <div class="bottom right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```css
.target {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#interface-reg {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#interface-reg div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 122px;
  height: 122px;
  background: red;
}

.offset-top-left {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #green;
}

.top {
  top: 0;
}
.right {
  right: 0;
}
.bottom {
  bottom: 0;
}
.left {
  left: 0;
}
```

Comment: When using cardinal properties like `top`/`left`/`bottom`/`right`, the element cannot be statically positioned (which is the default). In your case you are probably missing `position: relative` on the element you want to position. Also, `#green` is not a valid CSS color.

Comment: Thanks, color fixed but `position: relative;` still not revealing css properties

Comment: What do you mean by "revealing css properties"?

Comment: Can you share the result you're getting vs the expected result?

Comment: please put some more effort on debugging your code, and then post a more specific question with just the relevant details

Answer (score 0):

with this selector  `#interface-reg > div` you can select only childs that their parent is `#interface-reg` not other `div`.

also the color property in `background-color: #green;` is wrong .`background-color: green;`

```css
.target {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#interface-reg {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#interface-reg > div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 122px;
  height: 122px;
  background: red;
}

.offset-top-left {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}

.top {
  top: 0;
}
.right {
  right: 0;
}
.bottom {
  bottom: 0;
}
.left {
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="target">
  <div id="interface-reg">
    <div class="top left"><div class="offset-top-left"> hello</div></div>
    <div class="top right"></div>
    <div class="bottom left"></div>
    <div class="bottom right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```